# plt.ioff() isn't working. How do I plot several different graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
plt.ioff()
for i in range(0,len(variableList)):
    graph = lag1['VDC'].rolling(window=24).corr(other=lag1[variableList[i]])
    plt.title(variableList[i])
    plt.plot(graph)
    plt.axhline(y=0)
    plt.savefig(variableList[i])
```

I want to plot several different independent graphs. The default is in interactive mode where each new graph is plotted on the previous one. I read the document and found that I need to use plt.ioff(). However adding this line doesn't change anything.

Comment: Does "plot several different graphs" mean plot them all simultaneously, as subplots in one figure/window? or in different figures/windows? or plot them sequentially, one after the other? and with or without interactivity i.e. waiting for user to press a key between each plot/subplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interactive mode is used to obtain an event loop while continuiung the execution of the script. This can be useful to update a plot at several different points in a script, for doing quick animations or for working from within the console.
The interactive mode has nothing to do with new figures being created. I.e. you can have several figures or only one figure, both with interactive mode on or off.

To obtain a new figure in pyplot use

```
plt.figure()
```

pyplot commands executed after that will apply to this new figure.

The pyplot tutorial has a chapter on [Working with multiple figures and axes](https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html), where this is explained in detail.

Comment: Hi, when I change my original code from plt.plot(graph) to plt.figure(graph)  The following error occurred :  cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Comment: I did say `plt.figure()`, no `graph` here. This line is standalone, it needs to come at some point before `plt.plot(graph)` in the code.

Answer (score 2):

If you try the example in [non-interactive example, Usage Guide](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#non-interactive-example), the output is a set of three graphs indeed. Furthermore, `plt.ioff()` doesn't work if you set `%matplotlib inline`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

plt.ioff()
for i in range(3):
    plt.plot(np.random.rand(10))
    plt.show()
```

[image]

However, it saves plots with lines accumulated if you use `plt.savefig`.

```
%matplotlib inline

plt.ioff()
for i in range(3):
    plt.plot(np.random.rand(10))
    plt.savefig(f'{i}.png')
```

Also, it doesn't work if:

```
%matplotlib auto

plt.ioff()
for i in range(3):
    plt.plot(np.random.rand(10))
    plt.show()
```

So, for non-interactive figures, you should always use [object-oriented (OO) style](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#the-object-oriented-interface-and-the-pyplot-interface) to avoid such issues:

```
%matplotlib auto

plt.ioff()
for i in range(3):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))
    fig.savefig(f'{i}.png')
```